# How to secure upload to cloudfront by javascript sdk?

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are trying to setup a cloudfront distribution for an S3 bucket upload.
We are using the javascript aws sdk 2.1.8 to perform the upload.

How currently we use the cloudfront to upload is by setting

```
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: 'anyId', secretAccessKey: 'anything' });
AWS.config.s3BucketEndpoint = true;
AWS.config.endpoint = "xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

However, it seems like the accesskeyId and secretAccessKey is ignored. We can perform an upload regardless of the values. It can successfully upload to the bucket through cloudfront url.

We have bucket policy using the origin access identity to allow actions : "PutObject & GetObject"

But if we upload directly to s3 bucket, the credentials are validated.

Answer (score -1):

The credentials are verified - probably you have specified these credentials in distribution configuration (in Origin Access Identity). To restrict usage of CloudFront URL to upload you might want to use signed URLs functionality - it a way to restrict who can use your URL. More details are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html

Comment: updated link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html